# how to run causalImpact on a time series with multiple interventions?

Tags: r, time-series, causality, causalimpact

In CausalImpact package, one defines pre-period and post-period for a single intervention. However, in the scenarios where there are multiple interventions at irregular time intervals, is there a way to use causalImpact or other packages to estimate the impact? thanks.

Sample code below

```
library(CausalImpact)
x1 <- 100 + arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.999), n = 100)
x2 <- 25 + arima.sim(model = list(ma = 0.246), n = 100)
x3 <- 50 + arima.sim(model = list(ma = 0.126), n = 100)
y <- 1.2 * x1 + 0.8*x2 + rnorm(100)
y[71:100] <- y[71:100] + 15
y[91:100] <- y[71:100] + 30
time.points <- seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = 1, length.out = 100)
data <- zoo(cbind(y, x1, x2,x3), time.points)
matplot(data, type = "l")

pre.period <- as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-03-10"))
post.period <- as.Date(c("2020-03-11", "2020-04-09"))
impact <- CausalImpact(data, pre.period, post.period)
plot(impact)
```